# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'. -Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my first android project ever(just recently started)

Im having this problem in the gradle build:

[Gradle build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dCnG.png)

[app file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dCnG.png)

[image]
Would appreciate all the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0` yet.
Use either `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1` to have latest features (but unstable) or use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0` for the latest stable version.

Comment: Thanks It did solve my problem. But now I'm having this one: emulator: device fd:936
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: VT feature is not enabled, HAXM not working.
creating window 43 59 329 583
Error accepting connection, aborting

Comment: Install the newest HAXM driver from the Intel site. This driver accelerates the emulator. And use one of the x86 android system images.